# check for a value from a array of json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my snippet, how can I check in the array of json objects if there's a "status" of "DISCONNECTED"?

I tried,

```
if(data[].status["DISCONNECTED"].length){
    console.log(true);
}
```

but seems not working, any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [{"b_id":1,"name":"t1","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":3,"name":"t2","status":"DISCONNECTED"},{"b_id":4,"name":"t3","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":5,"name":"t4","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":6,"name":"t5","status":"CONNECTED"}];
  
  $.each(data,function(index,value){
    console.log(value.status);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Did you get an error? What does the console.log statement produce?

Comment: I want to check directly (not using the loop) the length of the json objects that has a status of "DISCONNECTED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using lodash (or don't mind including it), you can use its `.where` method:

```
var data = [{"b_id":1,"name":"t1","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":3,"name":"t2","status":"DISCONNECTED"},{"b_id":4,"name":"t3","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":5,"name":"t4","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":6,"name":"t5","status":"CONNECTED"}];

if (_.where(data, {status: 'DISCONNECTED'}).length) {
    console.log('exitsts');
}
```

Or without library, using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var a = data.some(function(val) {
    return val.status == 'DISCONNECTED';
});

if (a) {
    console.log('exists');
}
```

Comment: so which of the above two snippets you prefer to fit as an answer? It would be good if the script is cross browser (I don't intend to wait for the future)

Comment: Take `some()` - please see the edit @CodeDemon. The support is good, starting from IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
    "b_id": 1,
    "name": "t1",
    "status": "CONNECTED"
  }, {
    "b_id": 3,
    "name": "t2",
    "status": "DISCONNECTED"
  }, {
    "b_id": 4,
    "name": "t3",
    "status": "CONNECTED"
  }, {
    "b_id": 5,
    "name": "t4",
    "status": "CONNECTED"
  }, {
    "b_id": 6,
    "name": "t5",
    "status": "CONNECTED"
  }];

  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    if (value.status == "DISCONNECTED") {
      console.log(value.status);
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Wouldnt this do the trick?

Comment: I can just do that but I prefer to check the length of the json objects that contains a status of "DISCONNECTED"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your code seems works fine. what's the problem?

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [{"b_id":1,"name":"t1","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":3,"name":"t2","status":"DISCONNECTED"},{"b_id":4,"name":"t3","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":5,"name":"t4","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":6,"name":"t5","status":"CONNECTED"}];
  
  $.each(data,function(index,value){

if (value.status == "DISCONNECTED"){
 // DISCONNECTED founde!!
 console.log(value.status);
}
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to check directly (not using the loop) the length of the json objects that has a status of "DISCONNECTED"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [{"b_id":1,"name":"t1","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":3,"name":"t2","status":"DISCONNECTED"},{"b_id":4,"name":"t3","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":5,"name":"t4","status":"CONNECTED"},{"b_id":6,"name":"t5","status":"CONNECTED"}];
  
  $.each(data,function(index,value){
    var newObj = value;
    alert(newObj.status);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to check directly (not using the loop) the length of the json objects that has a status of "DISCONNECTED"

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var obj = arr[i];
    for(var key in obj){
        var attrName = key;
        var attrValue = obj[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to check directly (not using the loop) the length of the json objects that has a status of "DISCONNECTED"

Comment: zzzz you not told us